# regex: how to include the end of line in search result?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
#key1=value1|#key2=value2|#key3=value3
```

I am using this regex to match the keys and values:

```
/#(.*)\=(.*)[\|\v\h|]/gU
```

which works great for key1 and key2, but does not capture the key3

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eU6lV8/2

Any ideas how to capture key3?

Comment: Why not explode the string wiht `|` and then with `=`? If you really need a regex, try `#(.*?)=(.*?)([\v\h|]|$)`

Comment: Show the command you executed and the output.

Answer (score 5):

## Simple Solution

Make a line ending (`$`) a possible match after your key/value pair by replacing `[\|\v\h|]` with `(?:$|[\|\v\h|])`:

```
/#(.*)\=(.*)(?:$|[\|\v\h|])/gU
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oX0nY0/3)

## Better Solution

Even better, you could tweak your original regex for efficiency by getting rid of the `.*` groups (as suggested by anubhava in a now-deleted comment):

```
/#([^=]*)\=([^|]*)(?:$|[\|\v\h|])/gU
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oX0nY0/4)

## Explanation

The reason your original regex doesn't work is that `\v` and `\h` only match vertical and horizontal whitespace, respectively. They don't match the end of a line that isn't followed by any whitespace at all.

## A Word of Caution

That said, as [Wiktor Stribiżew said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080466/regex-how-to-include-the-end-of-line-in-search-result/37080504#comment61705768_37080466), it's often easier to just split the string, rather than doing complicated parsing with regex. Be sure you're not trying to solve an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426).